# PHP framework similar to Python Pylons

Tags: php, python, comparison, pylons, web-frameworks

What is most similar PHP framework to Pylons?
I mean mostly ideology of programming.

Comment: Pylons is a bit too long ago for me, but I found the Yii framework approachable from a python perspective. You might also check out the limonade php microframework (http://www.limonade-php.net/).

Comment: I don't recall the Protoss ever being interested in PHP in the first place.

Comment: If you have a Pythonic *ideology* (like Pylons have), would you not use Python? :-)

Comment: Cos' I need to learn some PHP framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methyl, Great php framework is Codeigniter, fully documented. Also there is Kohana, if you want php5 features.

Regarding your question, Since [benchmarking PHP vs Pylons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674739/benchmarking-php-vs-pylons) they are comparing smarty with pylons, it might be similar.

I would go for Codeigniter or Kohana. Behance.net is one of the sites build on Codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

Being primarily a Python developer, and having used Pylons, TurboGears, and Django, I would whole heartedly, 100% recommend Kohana 3.x.  To be completely honest I am not a huge fan of PHP, even though it is the language of choice at my current employer.  Given the choice I would use Python and Pylons.  But, using Kohana is just about the best framework I could hope for from PHP.  I hope I am not biases, considering I work with two developers on the Kohana development team. ;-)

PHP and Python are *very* different.  As such, there is no real equivalent of Pylons in PHP.  But, I would also say there is no real equivalent of Kohana in Python

Comment: I think I agree, but I would say that I found Pylons _much_ easier to pick up than Kohana (and I've got a lot more experience in PHP than Python).  It's possible this discrepancy is just because I'm a more experienced coder now learning Pylons than I was when I tried out Kohana.

Answer (score 1):

I used Pylons a few years ago. I don't think that there is any web framework in PHP very similar to it.

However, I find that [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) encourages several web development patterns used in Pylons. For example, in ORM, templating, testing, configuration files, MVC, etc. Some other MVC frameworks that can be compared to Pylons are [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) (which is inspired in Ruby on Rails) and the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) (one of the largest, with lots of components to be extended).